# Custom terminal with less

Tags: terminal, environment-variables, less, pager

Currently I have this in my "~/.profile":

```sh
export PAGER='env TERM=fox less'
```

However I just realized that this only works with "man", and not if you do
something like this:

```sh
less /etc/DIR_COLORS
```

to try to fix this, I created a "~/.lesskey" file:

```sh
#env
LESS = -i
TERM = fox
```

and installed by running "lesskey". Now when I run "less" the "LESS" variable is
recognized, but not the "TERM" variable. How can I have less use a custom
terminal?

Comment: @Fox http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2018-01/msg00008.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this for all your commands, just put

```
TERM=fox
```

in your .profile.   If you need it only for less, you could define an alias

```
alias less='TERM=fox less'
```